# K# Check Contain String

Tags: kentico

I have the location field and want to check if it contains certain string of text. If yes, then display the value, and if not just don't output anything. How is it written in K#. Thanks!

Something like below:
`{%If(CurrentDocument.Location contains "abc"){CurrentDocument.Location} Else {""} #%}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's:

```
{% CurrentDocument.Location.Contains("abc")?CurrentDocument.Location:"" #%}
```

Answer (score 0):

{% Location == "abc" ? "abc" : "" %}

Comment: Actually, I don't want _equal_. I want to check whether it _contain_ a substring, "abc" in this case

Comment: Please try adding some context around your code. It will help the OP.